# How to load the OpenGL glGenBuffers method in Delphi on Windows?

Tags: delphi, opengl

The following code tries to load the OpenGL `glGenBuffers` method but fails to do so. Could you help to comment what is the reason and how to work around ?

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  StrUtils, SysUtils, Windows;

var
  Library_OpenGL: HMODULE;

begin
  try
    Library_OpenGL := LoadLibrary('opengl32.dll');
    Writeln(Ifthen(GetProcAddress(Library_OpenGL, 'glGenBuffers') <> nil, ' glGenBuffers Success', ' glGenBuffers Failed'));
    Writeln(Ifthen(GetProcAddress(Library_OpenGL, 'glGenBuffersARB') <> nil, ' glGenBuffersARB Success', ' glGenBuffersARB Failed'));
    FreeLibrary(Library_OpenGL);

    Library_OpenGL := LoadLibrary('atioglxx.dll'); // ATI 4850
    Writeln(Ifthen(GetProcAddress(Library_OpenGL, 'glGenBuffers') <> nil, ' glGenBuffers Success', ' glGenBuffers Failed'));
    Writeln(Ifthen(GetProcAddress(Library_OpenGL, 'glGenBuffersARB') <> nil, ' glGenBuffersARB Success', ' glGenBuffersARB Failed'));
    FreeLibrary(Library_OpenGL);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we properly check the return of the API, instead of dumping if it fails or not, we get the answer to why it fails pretty quick.

Replace

```
Writeln(Ifthen(GetProcAddress(Library_OpenGL, 'glGenBuffers') <> nil, ' glGenBuffers Success', ' glGenBuffers Failed'));
```

with

```
Win32Check(GetProcAddress(Library_OpenGL, 'glGenBuffers') <> nil);
```

and we have an exception:

> EOSError: System Error.  Code: 127.
>  
>   The specified procedure could not be found

So the reason `GetProcAddress` fails is that the opengl library does not export a `glGenBuffers` function. A check with "depends" confirms that.

A quick search about missing functions in opengl leads us to [`wglGetProcAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374386%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The **wglGetProcAddress** function returns the address of an OpenGL
>   extension function for use with the current OpenGL rendering context.

If you read the documentation throughly, you'll notice that simply calling `gwlGetProcAddress` supplying `glGenBuffers` will fail. You need a rendering context for it to return the address of the function.

Below is my shortest project which succeeds in getting the function's address. It use a GUI application since a rendering context requires a window, and a default VCL form suits the requirements (see "remarks" in [`SetPixelFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd369049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). (Disclaimer: I don't know anything about opengl, code below is not necessarily correct, it also omits error checking which you should be really avoiding).

```
uses
  opengl;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Library_OpenGL: HMODULE;
  DC: HDC;
  PxFmt: TPixelFormatDescriptor;
  GLRC: HGLRC;
  glGenBuffers: procedure(n: GLsizei; buffers: PGLuint); cdecl;

begin
   Library_OpenGL := LoadLibrary('opengl32.dll');

   DC := GetDC(Handle);
   ZeroMemory(@PxFmt, SizeOf(PxFmt));
   PxFmt.nSize := SizeOf(PxFmt);
   PxFmt.nVersion := 1;
   PxFmt.dwFlags := PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW or PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL or PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
   PxFmt.iPixelType := PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
   PxFmt.cColorBits := 32;
   PxFmt.cDepthBits := 24;
   PxFmt.cStencilBits := 8;
   SetPixelFormat(DC, ChoosePixelFormat(DC, @PxFmt), @PxFmt);

   GLRC := wglCreateContext(DC);
   wglMakeCurrent(DC, GLRC);
   @glGenBuffers := wglGetProcAddress('glGenBuffers');
   Assert(@glGenBuffers <> nil);
   ...

end;
```

Answer (score 2):

While probably too late to be useful to the original questioner, the following might help others who find this question...

Delphi (possibly even very early versions) includes an `OpenGL` unit which provides basic functionality. I understand this is limited to functions present in OpenGL 1.1.

Delphi XE6 (released in April 2014 according to Wikipedia) added an `OpenGLExt` unit, including functionality up to OpenGL 4.3. This unit provides `glGenBuffers` and many other extension functions, but the extension functions are only loaded if your program explicitly calls `InitOpenGLext` (which itself just makes many `wglGetProcAddress` calls).

Using the two units together can save substantial effort.

I just got a simple tutorial working (just drawing a white triangle) using GLFW along with Delphi's `OpenGL` and `OpenGLExt` units.

Using GLFW in Delphi requires a unit to bind the GLFW functions, along with compiled GLFW DLLs. The following Github repository includes such a unit and DLLs together (though this isn't the one I used): https://github.com/neslib/DelphiGlfw

The essential calls before you can call extension functions are as follows. I've omitted error checking, but comments in the code should help with that.

```
uses Winapi.OpenGL, Winapi.OpenGLExt,
    glfw; //The glfw unit name may be different, depending where you obtained it.

var window:pGLFWwindow;
begin
    glfwInit; //Returns 0 if it fails.
    window:=glfwCreateWindow(640,480,pchar(utf8encode('My Test Window')),
        nil,nil); //Returns nil if it fails.
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Next line assigns function pointers for extension functions, so glGenBuffers will work.
    InitOpenGLext;

    // Add any other setup and your rendering loop here, and clean up after the loop.
    // ...
end;
```

Comment: You have my utmost gratitude, Mister.